# Data Encryption Standard (DES) + a SPRING BOOT authentication

Tags: spring, encryption, spring-boot, des

I am migrating from php platform to Java. I have Database full of users with stored passwords in Data Encryption Standard (DES). I would usually do something like this with custom authenticationService:

```
@Autowired
private AuthenticationServiceImpl authenticationService;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(authenticationService)
        .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}
```

Obviously not gonna work with bCrypt. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please, **NEVER EVER** store user passwords, not even with the strongest encryption ever to be invented, because it's inherently **insecure**. Store *salted password hashes* instead, with each salt being different for every password. Read this for a good overview on the subject: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your own [PasswordEncoder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html) which uses DES. It shouldn't be difficult and you can search how to decrypt/encrypt data with DES (as an [example](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-encrypt-and-decrypt-files-using-des.html)).

Just to let you know, *encrypting* passwords is a very, very, very bad practice (I would suggest that it borders being criminal), as if your DB and the key are exfiltrated, an attacker can very easily get access to the plain text passwords and try to re-use the login details on other sites.

Since you do have access to the plain text passwords, please consider to convert them to bcrypt and removing the DES encrypted password (from your DB and hopefully from any backups you might have)

Comment: Hmm well,i usually just store salted hash i create using Bcrypt.
something like this :  BCrypt.hashpw(employeeJPA.getEmail(), BCrypt.gensalt())  and than i store that value to db. Am i doing something wrong there? 

Problem right now is i am upgrading platform written in PHP by someone else 5-8 years ago and i have what i have. Not sure what to do know. Will think about it thanks anyways.

Comment: What you say you are doing with bcrypt is fine as it's a hash function, but DES is an **encryption** function, so it can be reversed... and that **is** a problem.

Comment: Ok got it. So what you suggest is get all users from db, de-crypt DES to string, then hash with bcrypt and store in hash in db. Was hoping there was an easier solution. The project i am working on is a small application for local business and they dont really care that much about security plus i do not have access to their entire code, just db, so i couldnt change the way they store passwords and authenticate user for log-in, even if i wanted to. Thanks anyway

Comment: If you don't mind do the following: let the person who owns this project/product know this, try to explain as best as you can the problems, and let him/her decide whether to spend time to make it more secure or not... at least you make it transparent for them :).